# How to make a sum row for two columns python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0    1     2     3
1    2     3     4
```

And I want to add a new row summing over two columns `[Col1,Col2]` like:

```
      Col1  Col2  Col3
0      1     2     3
1      2     3     4
Total  3     5     NaN
```

Ignoring `Col3`. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say dataframe, do you mean `pandas`? Then it should be tagged accordingly. And what have you tried, why did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas.DataFrame.append` and `pandas.DataFrame.sum` methods:

```
df2 = df.append(df.sum(), ignore_index=True)
df2.iloc[-1, df2.columns.get_loc('Col3')] = np.nan
```

Comment: jpp's answer is better, as it doesn't calculate the third column

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Note the final column will be converted to `float` since `NaN` is considered `float`:

```
import numpy as np

df.loc['Total'] = [df['Col1'].sum(), df['Col2'].sum(), np.nan]
df[['Col1', 'Col2']] = df[['Col1', 'Col2']].astype(int)

print(df)

       Col1  Col2  Col3
0         1     2   3.0
1         2     3   4.0
Total     3     5   NaN
```